# jquery append on button click showing text then disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am relatively new to jquery and having some difficulty.  I have been working on this for the past few hours.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form id = "params">
Type: <input id = "type" type = "text">
Parameters:<input type = "text">
Required: <input type = "checkbox" >
<button id = "addpa">Add Parameter</button>
<script>
$("#addpa").click(function() {
        $("#params").append("Parameters:<input type = \"text\"><br>Required: <input type = \"checkbox\" >");
});
</script>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is Have the user name the type of item they are creating.  After they can enter a list of paramaters.  Since each "type" will have a different number of parameters, I want them to be able to click the button and have an opportunity to add a new set of inputs.  When I click the button, the inputs show up then disappear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nearly got it.  Just take the button and script tags out of the form and put them at the bottom like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <form id = "params">
            Type: <input id = "type" type = "text">
            Parameters:<input type = "text">
            Required: <input type = "checkbox" >
        </form>
        <button id = "addpa">Add Parameter</button>
        <script>
            $("#addpa").click(function() {
                $("#params").append("Parameters:<input type = \"text\"><br>Required: <input type = \"checkbox\" >");
            });
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are submitting your form. Try changing it for a div.

```
<div id = "params">
    Type: <input id = "type" type = "text" />
    Parameters:<input type = "text" />
    Required: <input type = "checkbox" />
    <button id = "addpa">Add Parameter</button>
</div>


$("#addpa").click(function() {
        $("#params").append("Parameters:<input type = \"text\" /><br>Required: <input type = \"checkbox\" >");
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/GMxKr/)

Comment: Thanks.  When would I put it in a form vs a div?